# Can't do cast in LINQ with IQueryable?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm wondering how to get the query below to work:

```
IQueryable<TypeA> data  = ...;                  
data = data.OrderBy(x => ((TypeB)x.RelatedObject).Value);
```

The error I get is:

> The specified type member 'RelatedObject' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

I'm very new to C#, I think this is a compile problem because I know `RelatedObject` is of `TypeB`.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, Entity Framework does not know (enough) about the relation between TypeA and TypeB. If you can define it as a [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738520(v=vs.100).aspx), that would solve your problem.

If that is not possible, inserting [`.AsEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb335435(v=vs.100).aspx) should work:

```
data.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => ((TypeB)x.RelatedObject).Value);
```

What this will do, is having 'normal' LINQ performing the ordering, instead of the database (with an ORDER BY clause in the SQL query). Note that it returns an `IEnumerable<TypeA>` instead of an `IQueryable<TypeA>` - depending on what you do with this variable, this might cause more records to be loaded into memory than strictly necessary.

Comment: This has made Linq to SQL question to  Linq to Entities, thus fetching everything in memory by default

Comment: @MrinalKamboj I realized that already, but I didn't make it clear enough I suppose.

Comment: In my views its clear in your response, but not sure if it works for everyone using EF, who want to keep working with IQueryable

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you're only getting one specific type, you should be able to do something like this, assuming that EF knows about the inheritance.

```
IQueryable<TypeA> data  = ...;                  
data = data.OfType<TypeB>().OrderBy(x => (x.RelatedObject).Value);
```